# Japanese Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, keymap, japanese

I'd like to get a Japanese keyboard for a custom project (reason Japanese is good is the small space bar giving way to lots of modifier keys). I will be respraying the keys, so (superficially) the incorrect placement of things like brackets and at-sign shouldn't matter.

[image: JP Keyboard layout]

If I then used standard US/UK layout would the standard keys be back in their normal places, or would I need a more sophisticated key map?

Comment: What did you determine about this?

Answer (score 2):

Using a US/UK layout on a JP keyboard will result in the US/UK keycodes registering for their normal keys. Watch out for the backslash and backtick though.